# Setting functions in variables

Tags: php

While looking at someone's code today, I saw this:

```
public $setCookieFunction = 'setcookie';

$setcookie = $this->setCookieFunction;
```

Anyone knows how this works?

Thanks!

Comment: Just like this `$this->setcookie()`. Hey, it's PHP. It's explained here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

Comment: @AljoshaBre - You'd need the dollar sign before `setcookie()`, otherwise PHP will try to invoke the member function `setcookie()`. Also, there is no property `$this->setcookie()`, it is either `$this->$setCookieFunction()` or `$setcookie()`.

Comment: I just wrote how's it actually evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely invoked like this, with the same parameters as [`setcookie()`](http://php.net/setcookie):

```
$setcookie( string $name [, string $value [, int $expire = 0 [, string $path [, string $domain [, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]]]] );
```

Or:

```
$this->$setCookieFunction( string $name [, string $value [, int $expire = 0 [, string $path [, string $domain [, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]]]] );
```

The benefit here is that you can change `$this->setcookie` to whatever function name you want, and that function will get called across the class.